# BuildConfig.DEBUG (or equivalent) as a constant value

Tags: java, android, gradle, annotations, android-gradle-plugin

Assuming I have a custom annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface Test {
    boolean type();
}
```

I would like for the `type` parameter to be different based on the build type (but that would change automatically).

So I could do something **like** that:

```
@Test(type = BuildConfig.DEBUG)
public class Example {
}
```

But of course the code of the `Example` class won't compile because the value for the `BuildConfig.DEBUG` is not constant.

Anyone has any idea of creating a workaround for this? Maybe specifying some other parameters in gradle? I'm not interested in a solution that would make me manually change the `type` for the particular build. This way or the other. I'm looking for a way to do it automatically with the build.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**By gradle android plugin**

You can use gradle `buildConfigField`.
For example

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField "boolean", "TYPE", "true"
        }
        release {
            buildConfigField "boolean", "TYPE", "false"
        }
        ...
    }    
}
```

and then

```
@Test(type = BuildConfig.TYPE)
public class Example {
}
```

With `buildConfigField` you can also add some other type to your BuildConfig.

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField "int", "A_INT", "1"
            buildConfigField "String", "A_STRING", "\"string_1\"" // <---note the escape
        }

        release {
            buildConfigField "int", "A_INT", "2"
            buildConfigField "String", "A_STRING", "\"string_2\""
        }
    }
}
```

and if you have multiple flavors, you can define a field in each flavor:

```
productFlavors {
    // Define separate dev and prod product flavors.
    dev {
        buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_DEV", "true"
    }

    prod {
        buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_DEV", "false"
    }
}
```

With the same rules, you can add a value in your resources using `resValue`:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug{
            resValue "string", "dev_name", "Alice"
        }

        release {
            resValue "string", "dev_name", "Bob"
        }
    }
}
```

**By Code**

You can place a Class with values under src/debug/java/your.package.name and the same Class with different values under src/release/java/your.package.name

debug version

```
public final class MyConfigurations {
    public static final boolean TYPE = true;
    ...
}
```

release version

```
public final class MyConfigurations {
    public static final boolean TYPE = false;
    ...
}
```

And you can also play with flavors with the same logic of android gradle plugin (and in fact also this solution depends by that plugin)

Comment: It's actually quite surprising that this seems to be working for two reasons. 1. I'm almost sure I tried using my own custom `buildConfigField` (I use them quite frequently) instead of just `BuildConfig.DEBUG`, and I don't remember succeeding :D
2. If you look into the `BuildConfig` class the `DEBUG` field and e.g. your `TYPE` field look exactly the same, although the Android Studio won't let you use the `BuildConfig.DEBUG`.

Comment: So far, you're the best candidate for the bounty. Let's keep it going for a while still, and we'll see if someone comes up with some other solution as well.

Comment: Indeed the BuildConfig.DEBUG and BuildConfig.TYPE are really different. Yes, both of them are static const but while TYPE has a static and predefined value, BuildConfig.DEBUG is evaluated with a `parseBoolean("true/false")`

Comment: Oh yea actually, I guess I didn't remember that exactly right :P